# I want to advertise, but I don't want to publicize my personal#...unsure what options are available? (android handset Tracfone service)

Tags: calls

My understanding is there are options to advertise with a # that is-not my personal#, without getting a new cell-plan or new device.  What I don't know is whether I should be looking carrier-side, or android/handset side (I just swapped from a nearly-decade-long flip phone stubbornness just a couple weeks ago ;P )

Thank you for options to use "781 - 784 - 7707", or some randomly-generated #, to ring my personal handset *as if* the person really dialed my real number "123 456 7890" -- I know there are probably myriad options so any answer is appreciated, looking less for companies and more for what the landscape is for this (does VOIP come into play? Does it matter if I'm part of the futile crowd trying to 'limit google use on their android'? Have heard you can "play" google-voice to do call-forwarding for free, but imagine all calls are indefinitely stored...wouldn't really care, so long as it were **reliable** that I never miss a call to the business number, cannot afford it!!

Comment: This is a bit unclear: Do you want to place ads on other people devices but not include your number – or are you rather asking to see ads without revealing who you are? And what does this have to do with Google Voice forwarding calls?

Comment: You question is a bit confuse. Are you talking about making a call with or without sending your own phone number (e.g. temporary suppress number sending via `#31#`).

Comment: No I simply want to advertise, but NOT reveal my actual phone number.  So I need to get a new number(not a new *service*), that forwards to my handset (as-if the person had dialed my real number)  I believe "business number" and "vanity number" may be what it's called but am having trouble understanding what the options are... Just wanna advertise, without putting my personal number - I know there's ways of getting & using a "forwarding vanity number" so I can obscure/hide my phone#, but still post adverts with the vanity # that will ring my handset :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Voice was the only free service for getting a "new phone #", that - when someone calls it - would ring my cellphone.  I control it from my google-account, it works quite well but not well enough for me for primary business # (will still keep & use it as backup/for certain use)
Also there's plenty of app-based ways of getting a 2nd number, but google voice is the only free one.